# Excel Help: Search Column A, Sheet 1 for same value in Column A, Sheet 2, return value of Column B, same row in Sheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm surprised I couldn't find the answer on Google, maybe I am being silly.

I want to perform this function:-

- I have two sheets in Excel, lets say they are Sheet 1 and Sheet 2
- In Column A, Sheet 1 are names

  - I want to search Column A, Sheet 2 for the name
  - I want to return the corresponding adjacent value in the same row in Sheet 2

Any ideas how?

Comment: See this post, I think it's pretty much doing what you're after (although not exactly, but it would only take a minor tweak). However, this is for VBa, not worksheet function. http://superuser.com/questions/764875/how-to-count-two-different-column/766474#766474

Comment: Sounds like you want [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel - matching values in columns in different tabs and then pasting into another column if there's a match](http://superuser.com/questions/580787/excel-matching-values-in-columns-in-different-tabs-and-then-pasting-into-anoth)

Answer (score 3):

[Vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) does exactly this. Put this formula in B1 on sheet1 -

```
=Vlookup(A1,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,False)
```